# How i can send ajax request after render vue component?

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I have a component

html:

```
table
                tr(is="trcom" v-for="xml in xmls" :xml="xml")
```

js:

```
components: {
                trcom: {
                    props: ['xml'],
                    template: "<tr><td> {{ xml.query }} </td><td> downloading </td><td> downloading </td></tr>",
                    data: function(){
                        return {
                            position: "",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

can i send ajax request and replace template if ajax is done?

final template:

```
<tr><td> {{ xml.query }} </td> <td> {{ position }} </td> ...etc... </tr>
```

Comment: Your question in the title and in the body don't seem to match. Are you asking how to change the template after an ajax call, or are you asking how to perform an ajax call once the template is rendered? If you're wanting to perform an ajax call once the template is rendered, use the `mounted` lifecycle hook.

Comment: I need to make an ajax request for each element that will be added, and when ajax is executed, replace the template with another one, with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given our discussion in the comments below your question, I have a recommendation:

1) The elements that you're adding and want replaced after individual ajax calls should each be their own component.

2) Because you will be using individual child components, you should use the `mounted` lifecycle hook to perform your ajax calls.

3) Instead of "replacing" the components' templates, which I'm not sure is even possible, you can instead use conditional rendering to show an initial state vs. a post-ajax state.

Below is a toy example which also uses jQuery (the jQuery itself isn't necessary but is being used for simplicity):

**Child Component**

```
Vue.component('my-child-component', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <div v-if="initialized">
                I'm initialized! My prop value is: {{my_prop}}
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                I'm not initialized yet!
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['my_prop'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            initialized: false
        };
    },
    mounted: function() {
        //needed because we can't use "this" to reference the vue instance in our ajax call!
        var this_vue_instance = this;

        //this jQuery ajax call will execute as soon as this component has finished rendering
        $.post('/your/target/url', {any_data: 'you might need'}, function(data) {
            this_vue.initialized = true;
        });
    }
});
```

**Root Vue Instance**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var root_vue_instance = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                items: [0, 1, 2, 3]
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in items">
        <my-child-component :my_prop="item"></my-child-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is really bare-bones, but should server as a helpful example for implementing the solution to your current problem.